# Sum query evaluated locally on decimal column EF core + SQlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

I have run into an issue where our decimal columns which have a column type of `decimal(18,7)` are causing the Sum operation to be evaluated locally.

From what I've been able to find this is because [SQlite's numeric datatype's](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples). I thought that was just an example, but after changing our decimals to be `decimal(10,5)` instead of `decimal(18,7)` the sum operation is no longer run locally. This confuses me because from what I've understood the datatypes/affinities don't actually effect how the data is stored.

The fact that `decimal(10,5)` works seems to also contradict the following statement they make.

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite

We are using SQlite to store a copy of the data locally from a SQL Server Db, and the SQL Server uses `decimal(18,7)` so we can't change that for SQlite.

Is there any way to change this so we can use the linq Sum operation our decimal columns?

EDIT:

I found that if I cast the decimal to a double inside the Sum, it will work fine. Seems like it doesn't want to convert it to SQL because it will lose precision. At the moment I am calling ToList to pull the records in locally before doing the Sum, but this seems extremely wasteful

Does this mean that our decimal columns are actually stored as floating points in the database?